# How can I get a branch on gitlab into github?

Tags: git

So I need to take a branch I have in gitlab and put it on a branch in github. What are the commands and best way to do this?  I cloned the gitlab repo into a new directory and checked out the branch I want to move to github. Then I added a new remote for github. But I’m not sure how to merge or push this branch into github. Anyone have any ideas or has done this before and remember how they did it?  I’m not really good with git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add a remote to the repo that points to the github repo... then you can push to that other remote:

```
git remote add other-remote url-to-github-repo
git push other-remote some-branch
```

That should do

Comment: That seems to be the trick but now I’m getting an error about trying to move a file to big for github. So I removed the file from the branch and pushed those changes to gitlab. But when I tried again it is still complaining about that big file. Is that because it is in the history and I need to somehow remove it from the history?

Comment: github has a size limit for a single object of 100 Mbs.... yes, that will require removing... perhaps using LFS? I have no experience there and that's another question altogether. Even github has a page to read about it: https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/removing-files-from-git-large-file-storage